# spark streaming aggregation to calculate avg and min values

Tags: aggregation, spark-streaming

I have a DStream[String,Object] to which i need to calculate the avg, min and max values every one min. The Dstream is created from kafka to which msg are published every one min. I have the following code so far.

```
val reducedRecords =newRecords.reduceByKeyAndWindow(aggMetrics(_,_),Seconds(60))

reducedRecords.map{data => data._2}.foreachRDD { rdd =>      
  if (!rdd.isEmpty) {
    rdd.foreachPartition {
      iter => { 
        storeData(iter, confMap, ruleEng)
      }
    }
  }
}

} 

def aggMetrics(a:Object,b:Object) = {
a.copy(
    ts = math.min(a.ts,b.ts),
    minValue = math.min(a.minValue,b.minValue),
    maxValue = math.max(a.maxValue,b.maxValue),
    sum = a.value+b.value,
    count = a.count+b.count)
 }

 def storeData(iterator: Iterator[Object], confMap: Map[BackendAppSettings, String], ruleEng: StreamingEngine) = {
 // logic to store the data to db
 // while storing calculate avg using the sum/count
```

My questions are...

1.does this code looks good in terms of performance and also is there a chance 
of data loss when the data is partitioned?

2. Is using updatestatebykey is better option to the above one? If yes, what should be the update function in this case.
   Appreciate your answers.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you refer to with "data loss" in case data is partitioned?

Comment: what I meant was, will any data be missed during aggregation with the above logic??